# посмотреть команды в package.json

Tags: javascript, npm

Какая команда в консоле, чтобы посмотреть список доступных скриптов.

Допустим есть секция со скриптами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

раньше я набирал `npm ls или что то вроде этого` - вроде и видел список скриптов.

Comment: _npm ls_ - выводит список установленных пакетов

Comment: [issue на github](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4888)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того, чтобы вывести список доступных скриптов можно использовать [команду](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script)

```
npm run
```

> `npm run-script <command> [-- <args>...]`
>
> alias: npm run
>
> ### Описание
>
> ---
>
> Запускает указанную команду и объекта "scripts" в package.json. Если "command" не указан, будет выведен список доступных скриптов.

Answer (score 2):

Я использую для этого [npm-list-scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-list-scripts).
Установить можно командой:

```
npm install -g npm-list-scripts
```

Список скриптов можно просмотреть командой `npm-list-scripts`

Пример работы:
[image: пример]